# Multiple Overlaping Submeshes

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, vertices

and thank you for taking a moment to help me out.

Over the last few days I have been trying hard to bind an armature to a character model, but in vain, as no matter what options I have googled has not managed to help me get past this issue:

[image]

"Could not generate weights for all vertices."

"Your Mesh probably contains multiple overlaping sub meshes."

I have also tried taking on the 'Alternatives' that appears with the message but not been able to figure it all out. And out of options, I wonder if anyone is familiar with this issue and if so, have any solutions or tips. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an Avastar (addon) message... is it the last (Bento) version ? If yes, a shorter way could be to contact Gaia IW (Gaia Clary has developped Avastar)... or the Avastar group... (as here few know all this)

Comment: So Overlaping submeshes does not say you anything, dupliates making it hard on weight painting ect?

Comment: First thing, surely : remove doubles and be sure the model is symmetrical